# how to add a .so to a j2ee application

Tags: c++, maven, jakarta-ee

All is in the title. This code doesn't work because the type so isn't recognised by maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>libWrap</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
        <type>so</type>
       <scope>runtime</scope>

</dependency>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: you should probably use the `java.library.path` property to point to the additional native libs path, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35990698/5606016) on how to set it for maven build

Comment: I already did it with the argline option  using the surefire plugin but it doesn't work. I also copied the lib int the target path but it doesn't work neither

Comment: did you check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10226245/5606016)?